# How can I visualize a route in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a route in QGIS that visits every road/edge at least once. By using a marker line I can see the direction of the route, but it doesn't show the order of the segments (see the screenshot below). Is there any style/visualization that will allow me to see the order of the roads in the route?

Currently the route is a single polyline, but I can split it into segments if that will make it easier (the route is generated with Python code).

[image: Route example]

Comment: I'm guessing order is just a int value?

Comment: @NathanW yes, it can be represented as an int value. One solution would be to display that int as the edge label, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want something like this? :

[image: Example]

Unfortunately you will need to make it mostly manually. Use graduated symbology to classify your lines. Then change every symbol by adding marker with the offset and copy and paste colour code from line colour to marker border colour, and then set the colour of the line to desired uniform colour (black in my case).

If it is your constant task, maybe you should use some script to generate .qml-files.

Another option is after applying graduated symbology instead of adding markers, just add offset to every line to get something like that:

[image: Example2]

The vertices looks disjoint in this case, but overall route visualisation is better to my mind.

Comment: Can this be done with a single polyline, or do I need a separate line for each segment?

Comment: @Ralf, no, I don't think that you can do it with a single polyline.

Answer (score 0):

You could map your order value to a colour [intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) value and use these values along the polyline as your progress through the order of roads. Intensity is a good [pre-attentive](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/PP/) attribute so it should produce an easily interpretable result.